# ActionView::MissingTemplate despite redirect and render nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having a problem with a Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku. The method set_default_activities of activities controller ends on

```html
redirect_to root_path
```

but it appears to be looking for a view template called "activities/set_default_activities":

```html
2016-06-23T04:15:39.021209 #3] FATAL -- : 
2016-06-23T04:15:39.021744+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template activities/set_default_activities, application/set_default_activities with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

I have read the previous posts on this error and they appeared to suggest adding the line

```html
    render nothing: true
```

I have done this on the second-to-last line but the problem persists. What should I try next?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole method - perhaps the line where you redirect is never being reached.

Answer (score -1):

In your activities controller, modify the redirect line to:

```
redirect_to root_path and return
```